# Populate / store data from csv into django admin

Tags: django, csv

I want to get data from CSV and populate it to Django admin. but due to foreign key user I am not getting the desired result.

```
def handle(request):
        df = pd.read_excel('testdata.xlsx')
        obj=Account.objects.filter(email=df.user[0])
       
        for session_date,session_time,session_name,duration,i in zip(df.session_date,df.session_time,df.session_name,df.duration,obj):
         
            models = GuidedSession(session_date=session_date,session_time=session_time,session_name=session_name,duration=duration,user=i)
            # print(i)
            print(models
            # models.save()
       
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

(Views.py)

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
 
    objects = MyAccountManager()
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


 
class GuidedSession(models.Model):
    session_date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    session_time = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    session_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)     
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
    def __str__(self):
        s = str(self.session_name)
        return s
```

(Models.py)

Let me know the best way to do that.

Comment: can you post sample of csv file

Comment: you can check this https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: i try import_export but how i can handle foreign key as it gives id error

Comment: I think you need to define your resources files , but it will be better to share sample for csv

Comment: if you want to do it manually you can read CSV file get foreign key and get it or create it in database and fill the other models